# How to fix: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: r: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, weblogic

I´m setting up a new weblogic server to deploy and spring + angular application.

When I deploy it, server return the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
>        org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;

I'm using a weblogic 12c with java 8 to deploy the application. I checked that probably it's a problem with different versions of dependencies in a module. But I didn't found any problem on it.

This is the pom of my spring boot application:

```
<?xml ...>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>yyyyyyy</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>centinela</name>
<description>Description</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.60</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Exclude Spring Boot's Default Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fhtn-fd</groupId>
        <artifactId>fhtn-fd</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <systemPath>${pom.basedir}\lib\fhtn-fd.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the bottom of the pom, you will see the dependency of an artifact that contains some classes that are used in the project. This is the pom of this artifact.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>centinela-objects</groupId>
    <artifactId>fhtn-fd</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I don´t know if anyone can help me to deploy this application correctly.

### **Updated**

This is my weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<weblogic-version>12.2.1</weblogic-version>
<context-root>/dgfdg-backend</context-root>
<container-descriptor>
    <index-directory-enabled>true</index-directory-enabled>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>
```

I used "prefer-web-inf-classes" to true, to avoid problems with my customs jar. I can't use "prefer-application-packages" with "prefer-web-inf-classes", they are incompatible.

### **SOLVED**

Finally, I can resolve my problem. It was the way I created one of my own libraries that I used in my web service.

I was using it like an artifact but I need to create the jar using maven commands.

After create the library using "mvn clean package" and put it in my web service, I can deploy it without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception tell you that there is a class that doesn't have the default constructor without any parameter. Jackson library has problems with Weblogic and Spring.

Example of weblogic.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </jsp-descriptor>
  <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
      </prefer-application-packages>
  </container-descriptor>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I can help you with the setup, I was developing applications with Weblogic 12.2.1.2 and JDK 8, I don't have any problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I edited the question with my weblogic.xml configuration. I dont´t know if it can help you. The problem appears when I put the jar of classes inside the spring boot application.

Comment: Well you put part of the file, but it is important the versions of the tag you are using. Yes, spring boot has some problems deploying on Weblogic, but that is why you need to configure your project.

Comment: Two months ago I started a template using this repository. It could help you. https://github.com/cgonul/spring-boot-primefaces-weblogic

Comment: Finally, I resolved it using maven commands to create the jar of an external library. Thank you very much for your support. I put my solution at the bottom of the question.